# CodeIgniter User Authentication

Tags: codeigniter, authentication

I have authenticated users using code igniter successfully, but now if users type in the route to one the methods in one of my controllers, they can access it without logging in.

I would like to stop this access to users which havent logged in preferably without using a 3rd party User Auth Plugin.

I have this model code:

```
function login(){
    $data = array(
        'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
        'logged_in' => TRUE
    );
    $this->session->set_userdata($data);
} //function login()
function logged_in(){
    if($this->session->userdata('logged_in') == TRUE)
    {
        return TRUE;
    }
    return FALSE;
} //function logged in()
```

I have this controller code:

```
    function index($condition = FALSE){
    if($this->admin_model->logged_in() === TRUE)
    {
        $this->books_page(TRUE);
    }
    else
    {
        $data = $this->style_model->admin_area();
        $data['page_intro'] = 'Oops! Sorry, you must be logged in to view this page.';
        $this->load->view('admin/not_logged_in', $data);
    }
} //function index()
    function books_page(){
        $data = $this->style_model->admin_area();
        $data['category_query'] = $this->admin_books_model->get_book_categories();
        $data['page_title'] = 'Books';
        $data['query'] = $this->admin_books_model->get_books();         
        $this->load->view('admin/books/books_admin', $data);
    }    //function books_page()
```

Users who have not logged in cannot access the books method but any other methods after this they can access, i simply want to stop that access and pass them the error page informing them that they have to login.

Thanks in advance,
Tom

Comment: Just as a thought, you might consider getting into [TankAuth](http://konyukhov.com/soft/tank_auth/) for CodeIgniter. It's so secure and makes life **very** easy once you learn it. FWIW.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way is to split your logic into two (or more) controllers.

- A 'front end' controller - where the user does not need to be logged
  in for ANY of it
- A 'back end' controller(s) - where the user MUST be
  logged in for ALL of it

In your backend controller just do this

```
class Backend extends CI_Controller 
{
    public function  __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        if( ! ($this->admin_model->logged_in())
        {
            // Not logged in - so force them away
            redirect ('place login page here');
       }
    }
 }
```

Then EVERYTHING in `backend` controller is protected.

To take this concept further - look into using a `MY_Controller` and get all your backend controllers to extend from this.

Comment: Hi everyone thank you for your help I really appreciate it, at first I tried the answer from Slave and this worked perfectly however I liked the idea of using the MY_Controller class (TheShiftExchange Answer) because it is more efficient and uses less code (not repeating). I did some research on this and now I have it working, thanks again everyone really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Either I misunderstood your question, or the solution is very simple.

```
function books_page() {
   if(!$this->admin_model->logged_in()) {
      redirect('auth/login'); ## OR $this->load->view("error_page"); exit();
   }
   ## All your code, etc.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would declare a variable on top of the controller like this:

```
private $logged_in = false;
```

Then in the constructor I would initialise it like so:

```
$this->logged_in = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
```

Then you can disable the access to desired methods (or the complete controller if you put your check in the constructor):

```
if($this->logged_in)
{
   //do stuff
}
else
{
   redirect(base_url().'login');
}
```